# How would I make this so the while/else statement correctly repeats itself when the user input is incorrect?

Tags: java

I dont want it to say attempts remaining -1, i want it saying the 2 attempts after the 1st attempt is done, and it repeats the prompt of the user input.

I already tried looking on how to correctly do the 3 attempt thing, but for some reason, my program is not successfully doing it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Anagrams extends ShuffleWord{

   static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int score1 = 0;
      int score2 = 0;
      int score3 = 0;
      int attempts = 3;
      Random r = new Random();
      System.out.println("Your face looks familiar, what is your name?");
      String name = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Welcome " +  name + " to Anagrams, a game where the word is shuffled and you have to unscramble the word correctly!");
      System.out.println(" Please select a difficulty " + name + ", 1 being easy, 2 being normal, and 3 being hard.");
      int difficulty = input.nextInt();
      switch (difficulty) {
         case 1:
            // 6 letter words
            final String[] wordlist1 = {"string", "switch", "system" , "static" , "public" , "python" , "method" };
            String word1 = wordlist1[r.nextInt(wordlist1.length)]; 
            System.out.println("Your scrambled word is:" + shuffle(word1)); 
            System.out.println("Please type the word");
            String thisisjustsoitworks1 = input.nextLine();
            String userword1 = "";
            final List<String> wordy1 = Arrays.asList(wordlist1);
            while (attempts -- > 0 && !wordy1.contains(userword1));
            {
               userword1 = input.nextLine();
               if (wordy1.contains(userword1))
               {

                  score1 += 50;
                  System.out.println(name + ", Your current score is:" + score1); 

               }
               else
               {
                  System.out.println("Incorrect. Number of attempts remaining:" + attempts);

               }
            }
            break;
         case 2:
            // 15-16 letterwords
            final String[] wordlist2 = {"computerscience" , "primitivedatatype" , "booleandatatype" ,};
            String word2 = wordlist2[r.nextInt(wordlist2.length)]; 
            System.out.println("Your scrambled word is:" + shuffle(word2)); 
            System.out.println("Please type the word");
            String thisisjustsoitworks2= input.nextLine();
            String userword2 = input.nextLine();

            List<String> wordy2 = Arrays.asList(wordlist2);

            if (wordy2.contains(userword2))
            {

               score2 += 150;
               System.out.println(name +", Your current score is:" + score2); 

            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("game over");
            }
            break;
         case 3: 
            final String[] wordlist3 = {"objectorientatedprogramming" , "primitivedatatype" , "booleandatatype" ,};
            String word3 = wordlist3[r.nextInt(wordlist3.length)]; 
            System.out.println("Your scrambled word is:" + shuffle(word3)); 
            System.out.println("Please type the word");
            String thisisjustsoitworks3 = input.nextLine();
            String userword3 = input.nextLine();

            List<String> wordy3 = Arrays.asList(wordlist3);

            if (wordy3.contains(userword3))
            {

               score3 += 300;
               System.out.println (name + ", you gained" + score3  + "points, your total score is;" + score3); 

            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("game over");
            }
            break;






         default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Difficulty");
      }
   }
}
```

Suffle method code

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;





 /* Java program to shuffle a word randomly5
 */
public class ShuffleWord {



   //public static void main(String[] args) {
//        ShuffleWord sw = new ShuffleWord();
//
//        String word = "Hello";
//
//        String shuffled = sw.shuffle(word);
//
//        System.out.println("Original word:"+word);
//
//        System.out.println("Shuffled word:"+shuffled);





   /*
    * Shuffles a given word. Randomly swaps characters 10 times.

    * @param word

    * @return

    */

   public static String shuffle(String word) {

      String shuffledWord = word; // start with original

      int wordSize = word.length();

      int shuffleCount = 10; // let us randomly shuffle letters 10 times
      for(int i=0;i<shuffleCount;i++) {
         //swap letters in two indexes
         int position1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, wordSize);

         int position2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, wordSize);

         shuffledWord = swapCharacters(shuffledWord,position1,position2);
      }
      return shuffledWord;

   }



   /**

    * Swaps characters in a string using the given character positions

    * @param shuffledWord

    * @param position1

    * @param position2

    * @return

    */

   private static String swapCharacters(String shuffledWord, int position1, int position2) {

      char[] charArray = shuffledWord.toCharArray();

      // Replace with a "swap" function, if desired:

      char temp = charArray[position1];

      charArray[position1] = charArray[position2];

      charArray[position2] = temp;

      return new String(charArray);

   }

}
```

Output

Your face looks familiar, what is your name?
thomas
Welcome thomas to Anagrams, a game where the word is shuffled and you have to unscramble the word correctly!
Please select a difficulty thomas, 1 being easy, 2 being normal, and 3 being hard.
1
Your scrambled word is:static
Please type the word
a
Incorrect. Number of attempts remaining:-1

Comment: Could you please include your `shuffle()` method in your post? This would help us to test the flow better (you can [edit] the question and provide a [mcve]).

Comment: it is edited, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**attempts remaining -1** is getting printed because of `;` at the end of `while` loop(case 1:) in your code.

```
while (attempts -- > 0 && !wordy1.contains(userword1));
```

Due to this, `attempts` is getting decremented to `-1`, and after that program is taking user input.

Comment: @sokol Please consider [accepting the answer if it helped you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)